# Raise user defined SQL error and capture it in code

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to raise a user defined error from one stored procedure to a c# code. I have a stored procedure that assign employees to users, if you already assigned an employee to user 1 for example and you try to do the same thing again, the stored procedure should raise an error saying, "This association already exists" and return a code, for example 1 and a description of the error. The problem is that in c sharp is not passing by the catch part. here is the code:

```
public bool InsertUser(Guid userId, string[][] IDs, AppParams myParams)
{
    bool flag = false;
    SqlTransaction transaction = null;

    using (var dbConn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                dbConn.Open();
                cmd.Connection = dbConn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "InsertUser";

                transaction = dbConn.BeginTransaction();
                cmd.Transaction = transaction;

                for (int i = 0; i < IDs.Length; i++)
                {
                    flag = false;
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", userId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmployeeId", IDs[i][0]);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyId", myParams.ApplicationId);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedUserId", myParams.User.UserId);

                    //add output parameter
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
                    cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int, 4);
                    cmd.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ErrorMsg", SqlDbType.VarChar, 300);
                    cmd.Parameters["@ErrorMsg"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    var returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@ReturnValue"].Value);
                    flag = returnValue.Equals(0);

                    if (!flag)
                    {                                                                
                        if (cmd.Parameters["@ErrorMsg"].Value != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            this.ErrorModel.HasError = true;
                            this.ErrorModel.ErrorMessage = cmd.Parameters["@ErrorMsg"].Value.ToString();
                        }

                        transaction.Rollback();                     
                        return false;                                
                    }
                }
                transaction.Commit();           
            }

            catch (SqlException sqlex)
            {               
                this.ErrorModel.HasError = true;
                this.ErrorModel.ErrorMessage = sqlex.Message;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {           
                this.ErrorModel.HasError = true;
                this.ErrorModel.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            }           
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

here is my SQL code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertUser]
(
    @UserId             uniqueidentifier,
    @EmployeeId         int,
    @CompanyId          uniqueidentifier,
    @SystemStatusId     int = 1,
    @ModifiedByUserId   uniqueidentifier,
    @ID                 int output,
    @ErrorMsg           nvarchar(300) = NULL output
)
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ReturnVal int

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @ReturnVal = 0;
    SET @ErrorMsg = null;

    --  check for existing combination
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[UserRel]
               WHERE [UserId] = @UserId 
                 AND [EmployeeId] = @EmployeeId
                 AND [CompanyId] = @CompanyId
                 AND [SystemStatusId] = 1)
    BEGIN
            SET @ReturnVal = 1;
            SET @ErrorMsg = 'Item already Exist in Database'            
            RAISERROR @ErrorMsg, 0, 0
            GOTO ProcedureExit;
    END

    -- Insert statement
    INSERT [dbo].[UserRel]
    (
        [UserId],
        [EmployeeId],
        [CompanyId],
        [SystemStatusId],
        [ModifiedByUserId],
        [ModifiedDate]
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @UserId,
        @EmployeeId,
        @CompanyId,
        @SystemStatusId,
        @ModifiedByUserId,
        sysdatetimeoffset()
    )

    IF( @@ERROR <> 0 )
        BEGIN
            SET @ReturnVal = 2;
            SET @ErrorMsg = 'Failed to INSERT [dbo].[InsertUser]'
            GOTO ProcedureExit;
        END
    ELSE
        SET @ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

ProcedureExit:    
        RETURN @ReturnVal;

END
```

Comment: Show us the SQL code also.

Comment: Does the stored procedure raise an error (`raiserror`)? or does it just give a particular return value? in the latter case: why would we expect to see an exception? you aren't throwing anything... in the former case: what is the severity level of the custom error in `raiserror` ? (< 16 is a warning / information only; only >= 16 cause exceptions)

Comment: I'll add the sql in one minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that in c sharp is not passing by the catch part.

Because in the C#, there **was no exception**. You simply checked the return value of the stored procedure, and then decided to rollback and `return false;`. If you want an exception: `throw` an exception.

Alternatively, if the SQL issues a `raiserror` with severity 16 or higher, an exception will be observed automatically.

Incidentally, it is not clear that your transaction is correctly terminated in the case of a genuine exception. I would suggest moving the rollback code into the `catch` block. Since you do the exact same thing regardless of which exception you catch, there is no benefit in the `catch (SqlException sqlex)` block - so you might as well remove that.

Comment: Yes is truth. the catch for SQL doesn't make any sense. I'll check the raiseerror method, I should have something wrong. Microsoft suggest using THROW, but I'm using SQL 2008. I believe RAISEERROR() should do the same.

Comment: @rgx71 the issue here looks to be the severity; severity of 0 is *not an exception* - it needs to be >= 16 to count as an exception

Comment: You are right! that's was the problem, now is firing the catch in c sharp code, thanks Marc!